# pyusb won't install

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb

I'm trying to setup some python scripts for controlling low-level USB functions. In order to do this, I've found that two libraries need to be installed: libusb and pyusb. I first installed libusb and was successful, but now I'm having problems with pyusb (version 1.0.0).

I tried to install pyusb using the recommended command (in the pyusb folder): python setup.py install
From the output after running this command, it looks like it has installed with no problems. But when I try to run my simple program it gives an error:

```
  File "/Users/michael/Desktop/usb.py", line 1, in 
    import usb.core
ImportError: No module named core
```

My python script tries to import usb.core, so if there's no module, then pyusb didn't install.

[Other people have had the same problem](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyusb-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00367.html). Their approach was to uninstall the old versions of pyusb, but to my knowledge, I have no previous installations.

**How would it be possible to install the pyusb library?**

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate your help.
--m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script, which you have decided to call `usb.py`, is being imported in place of the `usb` package provided by pyusb. Rename your script.

Comment: @user547398 - If this answer solved your problem then you should mark it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade pyusb
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked for me as well --upgrade pyusb did the trick :D